# swig in c# - HandleRef could not be found in portable class library

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8.1, swig, portable-class-library

I'm tring to wrap my c++ code to c# with using Swig. If the output destination of C# files is class library , there is no error and succesfully build.

However I want to support both windows phone 8.1 and windows 8.1 because of this reason I'm using portable class library rather than normal class library. In this situation I'm getting error that says;

> The type or namespace name 'HandleRef' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Runtime.InteropServices' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I really don't know what I am missing. What is the solution of this problem?
My guess windows phone 8.1 and windows 8.1 does not support HandleRef but I'm not sure. If it so, What should I do?

Comment: HandleRef isn't supported in PCL (as you can check from MSDN). You _may_ replace it with IntPtr (assuming you _need_ it) but in that case you have to take care by yourself to avoid GC issues (handle to an object GCed because not in use).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti If I need to replace HandleRef with IntPtr , how can I do that?. Swig automatically use HandleRef and I couldn't see any example/guide for me to how I can change this.

Comment: Quite complex probably... There are 61 references to HandleRef in `Lib\csharp\*` of Swig...

Answer (score 4):

This question is a bit older, but having had the same problem when using .NET Core I thought I'd share my Solution.

---

### Change the imtype and csbody

To tell SWIG to stop using `HandleRef` you have to change the `%typemap(imtype)` and `%typemap(csbody)` of all default (or of specific) types.

`imtype` specifies the type that appears in your `modulenamePINVOKE` method parameters. Change it to something that can be marshaled from/to a pointer type.

`csbody` replaces the entire body of your `SWIGTYPE_` classes, meaning you'll have to implement you own (You have to, to change the variable that is stored as `HandleRef`). If your new implementation doesn't have a `getCPtr` method you have to change `%typemap(csin)` as well

Here is an example that uses `System.IntPtr` instead of `HandleRef`, place it at the top in your interface file:

```
%typemap(imtype) SWIGTYPE, SWIGTYPE *, SWIGTYPE &, SWIGTYPE [], SWIGTYPE (CLASS::*) "System.IntPtr"
%typemap(csin) SWIGTYPE, SWIGTYPE *, SWIGTYPE &, SWIGTYPE [], SWIGTYPE (CLASS::*) "$csinput.Pointer"

%typemap(csbody) SWIGTYPE *, SWIGTYPE &, SWIGTYPE [], SWIGTYPE (CLASS::*) %{

  private volatile System.IntPtr swigCPtr;

  protected $csclassname() 
  {
    swigCPtr = System.IntPtr.Zero;
  }

  internal System.IntPtr Pointer
  {
    get
    {
      return swigCPtr;
    }
  }
%}
```

Note: `SWIGTYPE` is a placeholder for any type.

Reference:
[SWIG 3.0 Documentation - Chapter 20 "SWIG and C#"](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#CSharp)

Comment: ca you please provide more details about how to fix this? Where this changes should be applied?