# SWIG: SWIGTYPE_p_void undefined when generating C# wrapper

Tags: c#, c, swig

When generating a wrapper for a C (not C++) library, the generated C# wrapper code is missing definitions for the types `SWIGTYPE_p_void`, `SWIGTYPE_p_uint32_t` et. al. that are used throughout the generated code.

Are there files I need to include in my `.i` file to enable cause these to be generated? As command line options to SWIG I use only the `-csharp` and `-namespace` options.

Directors are not enabled because enabling directors yields the error `Error: Directors are not supported for C code and require the -c++ option`

How can I enable generation / inclusion of the `SWIGTYPE_p_*` types?

I have tried the approach described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37846128/112125), but it only solves issues partially (for example, return types of functions still have `SWIGTYPE_p_void`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was that SWIG crashed in the middle due to too long filenames for function pointer types with a lot of parameters ...