# How to modify SWIG interface file for using pocketsphinx with .net core?

Tags: c#, c++, swig, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I have .net core (.net core app 1.1) application. I want to integrate pocketsphinx by using the [official spinx wrapper](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx/tree/master/swig/csharp).

But I get a lot of errors:

> [CS0234] The type or namespace name 'HandleRef' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Runtime.InteropServices' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

How I should modify SWIG interface file? I checked all *.i files in pocketsphinx and sphinxbase to try apply solution from another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37846128/8015749), but I can't find any appopriate to change **%typemap(imtype)** and **%typemap(csbody)** entries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [swig in c# - HandleRef could not be found in portable class library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30978652/swig-in-c-sharp-handleref-could-not-be-found-in-portable-class-library)

Comment: thanks for answer, but I have no idea how to apply this soltion to sphinx

Comment: I change my question for be more specific.

Comment: Answer says to place it on top of the interface file (pocketsphinx.i and sphinxbase.i). You open the file in a text editor and make the required changes.

Comment: Is there any code example which could show how this would work?